# What is an "em" if the font-size of the document is specified in ems?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-size

In CSS, an `em` is a relative unit based on the font-size of the document.  So, what exactly is an `em` then, if the font-size of the document *itself* is measured in ems?  Suppose we say:

```
<style type = "text/css">
body
{
    font-size: 1em;
}
</style>
```

So, an `em` is now recursively defined.  So how is this handled by the browser?

The [W3C docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html) say:

> The 'em' unit is equal to the computed value of the 'font-size'
>   property of the element on which it is used. The exception is when
>   'em' occurs in the value of the 'font-size' property itself, in which
>   case it refers to the font size of the parent element. It may be used
>   for vertical or horizontal measurement. (This unit is also sometimes
>   called the quad-width in typographic texts.)

But what if the element is `document.body`, so there is no parent element?

Comment: `em` is based on the `font-size` of a given element, or if it's set on `font-size`, then it's relative to that of its parent. If you want a unit that's relative to the `font-size` of the document root, that would be `rem`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`body` is not the document root element — that's a very common misconception. The parent element of `body` is `html`, whose default font size matches the browser's default font size setting (typically `16px`).<sup>1</sup>

This applies even if you set a `font-size` value in ems on *both* `body` and `html`. So if you did this:

```css
html, body { font-size: 2em; }
```

Then, assuming a default font size of `16px` as set by the user, `html` will have a font size of `32px` (twice the default font size) and `body` will have a font size of `64px` (twice of its parent, `html`).

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>To be precise, the `html` element's default font size is [the initial value, `medium`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/fonts.html#font-size-props), which according to the spec corresponds to the preferred default font size as set by the user.</sub>

Comment: Is the `16px` default mandated by some standard, or is it just a value which most (all?) browsers happen to follow?

Comment: @Channel72 You can change what size the browser uses by default in the user preferences in all important browsers.

Answer (score 0):

It will take the browsers' default value of 16px if no parent element has defined it.

Also see this: http://pxtoem.com/

Answer (score -2):

It'll be relative to whatever the browser's default font-size is, which WILL be specified in a physical size, e.g. '10pt'.

Comment: No, your example is misleading. The default font-size in a browser is not usually specified in `pt` but in `px`. E.g. both Chrome and Firefox only allow to specify the browser default font-size in `px`.