# How to work out EM based media query

Tags: css, media-queries, font-size

I'm trying to work out how to use EM media queries in my latest project. However after some testing I've found that the media queries are ever so slightly off and I can't work out why. It might have something to do with it using the parents font size instead of the body. My body is set to `14px` and my workings out look like:

```
$break-small: 22.8571em; //320px
$break-smallish: 40em; //560px
$break-med: 54.8571em; //768px
$break-medish: 68.5714em; //960px
$break-desk: 73.1428em; //1024px
```

body font size:

```
body{
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

*(from my SCSS breakpoint variables) From what I understand I did: 768 / 14 (base font size) = width in em's

Say I've a `div` called header, there is no `font-size` set on this `div`, only children of this `div`. Surely it would still then use the body `font-size`?

Comment: you can always check.  I like to use chrome developer tools, where I either look for the rule that is setting the font size, or for more immediate results, you can check the computed styles.  Because there is no code and any code included might not accurately portray the setup in this case, I would suggest checking it yourself in chrome or whatever developer tools you prefer.

Comment: It's definately showing the body's ```font-size: 14px;```

Comment: So then, in what way is it "slightly off"? Can you describe the problem in more detail and perhaps provide screen captures?

Comment: The measurements are off by how much? Also, if testing on a desktop machine vs. mobile, some browsers will include the scrollbar (~15px) in the viewport size (IE, Firefox, Opera) and some do not (Chrome, Safari). Sometimes that can throw off testing.

Answer (score 6):

Ems in media queries are never based on the font size of `body`, or any other element for that matter. They always refer to the default font size set by the user in the browser preferences. In most browsers this default font size is around 16px, and in CSS this corresponds to the initial value of the `font-size` property which is `medium`. From the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#units):

> Relative units in media queries are based on the initial value, which means that units are never based on results of declarations. For example, in HTML, the ‘em’ unit is relative to the initial value of ‘font-size’.

This same default font size is inherited by the root element, which is `html`, *not* `body` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10470727/what-is-an-em-if-the-font-size-of-the-document-is-specified-in-ems/10470734#10470734)). Specifying a relative font size on `body` just means `body` bases its own calculation on the computed font size of `html`. This being stated, note that setting `font-size` on `html` will *not* affect how ems are calculated in media queries either.

Comment: nice i didnt knew that & i was just trying to figure this out... **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/UjgUj/2/)**

Comment: Thanks for the great info. So basically I need to work my widths out based on the browser default for most users, that being 16px?

Comment: Knowing this, it seems to me like using em's here is a really bad idea because you don't know for sure the default size of someones browser font, yet I see people use this all the damn time?  Why is that?

Comment: @Michael: I can't say for sure, but my guess is that some people still adjust their browser font sizes because it scales with all websites except the ones that exclusively use absolute values for font sizes. Using ems for media queries and layouts ensures that the layouts will scale properly with these user preferences, since the whole point of the em unit is to be a relative unit and not a fixed absolute unit.

Answer (score 0):

Your guesswork is correct, the `em` unit sets the font size relative to the parent element's font-size, not relative to the document root. If you're looking for the latter you're looking for the `rem` unit, but [browser support](http://caniuse.com/rem) might be a problem for you, depending on your application.

See the following Fiddle for a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/afp46/

HTML:

```
<span >This is text</span>

<div><span >This is text</span></div>

<span><span>This is text</span></span>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    font-size: 14px;
}

div {
    font-size: 16px;
}

span {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

Comment: Your answer is from 3/12/2014, so I just wanted to clarify that browser support for `rem` units now is perfect across the board. **Note:** Opera Mini doesn't support `rem` units but we all know that [Opera Mini works very differently than other browsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_Mini) and lacks a lot of support for even basic CSS features, and that's intentional.

Answer (score 0):

I would change that to body font size 100% and then you have the flexibility of EMs and %s site wide

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend you do font-sizing with `rem`, which stands for "root em". It's much more consistent. Read more about it here:  http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/font-size-with-rem

Also, I would recommend adding this to your CSS:

```
html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
}
```

Now, your rems or ems will be easy to convert. 10px font-size would be 1rem or 1em. Nice, right? :) Again, use rems, its a much better practice these days.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code. I have already used this my last project it working in fine. so please try.

```
// Small screens
@media only screen { } /* Define mobile styles */

@media only screen and (max-width: 40em) { } /* max-width 640px, mobile-only styles, use when QAing mobile issues */

// Medium screens
@media only screen and (min-width: 40.063em) { } /* min-width 641px, medium screens */

@media only screen and (min-width: 40.063em) and (max-width: 64em) { } /* min-width 641px and max-width 1024px. */

// Large screens
@media only screen and (min-width: 64.063em) { } /* min-width 1025px, large screens */

@media only screen and (min-width: 64.063em) and (max-width: 90em) { } /* min-width 1025px and max-width 1440px  */

@media only screen and (min-width: 90.063em) { } /* min-width 1441px, xlarge screens */

@media only screen and (min-width: 90.063em) and (max-width: 120em) { } /* min-width 1441px and max-width 1920px */

// XXLarge screens
@media only screen and (min-width: 120.063em) { } /* min-width 1921px, xxlarge screens */
```