# CSS custom properties (variables) in <picture> <source> sizes

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design, css-variables

I'm trying to best describe to the browser which image to pick from a `srcset` list using the `sizes` attribute.

Basic is:

```html
<picture>
  <source 
    type="image/jpeg" 
    media="(min-width: 1024px)" 
    srcset="a.jpg 1024w, b.jpg 1200w, c.jpg 2048w, d.jpg 2400w" 
    sizes="100vw"
  >
  <img src="e.jpg">
</picture>
```

Now you might have a "max viewport" at which point your webpage "stops growing", so you add a media query in your sizes:

```html
<source
  ...
  sizes="(min-width: 1200px) 1200px, 100vw"
>
```

Your image might also have some padding, so you might be tempted to use `98vw` instead of `100vw` but that's not always accurate if the paddings are in pixels for example, so what you can do instead it use `calc`:

```html
<source
  ...
  sizes="(min-width: 1200px) 1200px, calc(100vw - 20px)"
>
```

So far we've only been using *absolute* units, but I've read you can also use *context-dependent* units like `em`:

```html
<source
  ...
  sizes="(min-width: 1200px) 1200px, calc(100vw - 2em)"
>
```

Interestingly, that means the browser must be aware of the styles being applied to the image (since `em` can change based on CSS). So if this is true, **could you use CSS custom properties (or "CSS variables") in your sizes?**

```html
<source
  ...
  sizes="(min-width: 1200px) 1200px, calc(var(--six-columns) - var(--image-padding))"
>
```

Thanks!

---

As a bonus question: any idea where I could find the browser support for such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this is NO!

When using `em` as a unit inside the `sizes` attribute, the browser will use a fixed predetermined size (14px in chrome apparently, determined experimentally).

In the end, no information actually comes from CSS, and CSS custom properties aren't actually usable that way.

Comment: use em there is like using em inside media query: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23614634/8620333

Comment: Here's a reduced test case to prove that this doesn't work: https://output.jsbin.com/katigokoja/1