# Is the default font-size of every browser 16px? Why?

Tags: html, css

CSS3 defines a new length unit for `font-size` called `rem`. This allow us to compute element's `font-size` relate to the root element (html element).

To compute the `font-size` more easily , we usually assume the root element's `font-size` is `16px`, therefore the CSS usually ends up like this:

```
html { font-size:62.5%; } // 10px = 16px * 0.625
```

So, every element height with `rem` is relative to `10px`, for example

```
p{ font-size : 1.4rem ;} // 14px = 10px * 1.4
```

I cant find why we assume we can multiply by `16px`? How can we trust every browser will have the same base value of `16px`? Is there is a standard description about the pre-defined `16px`?

**Ref**

- [MDN font-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size)
- [W3C rem](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-values-3/#font-relative-lengths)
- [CanIUse about rem](http://caniuse.com/#feat=rem)
- [Github skeleton.css](https://github.com/dhg/Skeleton/blob/master/css/skeleton.css)

Comment: Probably tradition. The initial value of `font-size`, which is used when calculating the default font size of `html` as well as calculating `rem` and `em` in media queries, is `medium`. The 16px comes from user preferences within the browser. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10470727/what-is-an-em-if-the-font-size-of-the-document-is-specified-in-ems/10470734#10470734

Comment: Thank you for asking, monjer, and thank you for answering, @Stewartside  -- I've been trying to figure this out for the past 2 hours

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The base `font-size` is determined by the users pre-defined preferences within the browser.

In almost every browser, 16px is the standard for proportional fonts. This can also change dependant on if the font uses serifs or is a fixed width font.

Just remember, `em` is relative to the element it is used on or relative to the inherited parents `font-size`, and is proportional to that. `rem` however, uses the root html elements.

For example:

```css
html {
  font-size: 16px;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 2em; // 32px
}
p {
  font-size: 1em; // 16px
}
.someClass {
  font-size: .75em; // 12px
}
.someClass p {
  font-size: 2em; // 24px
}
.someClass p .test {
  font-size: 1.25rem; // 20px
}
```

```html
<html>
<h1>2em Title Text</h1>
<p>Normal Element Text</p>
<div class="someClass">
  someClass font size
  <p>SomeClass with em</p>
  <p><span class="test">someClass p element with class test</span>
  </p>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: Out of curiosity... is keeping the design the across browser/devices worth it if you don't let users st bigger font size preferences? For example, older people tend to "up" their font size because it helps them read better. If you set the absolute value in body or html, then the user preferences are ignored. Is that worth over keeping the design?

Comment: @Chayemor now this depends entirely on your preferences on how you want your website to look. If you want it pixel perfect according to a design across every OS & browser then setting it needs to be done. If you're open to it moving etc then sure don't set it in your CSS. In my experience, only the very tiniest of users actually change their font size and they are usually of a good technical knowledge because it is hidden away in browser settings and would know how to get round it.

Comment: I thought the same but wanted to get another opinion on the matter. In the end I judge on a per-site basis. If the design allows for a bit of movement, then 100% it is. If it's pixel-perfect, then hello absolute value of PX. Thanks.

Comment: You probably want to avoid setting a px value as font-size in the root element as this will block scaling your website if the user changed the default font-size for accessibility.

Comment: @WoutDeRooms I second this as I've just encountered the same issue.

Comment: How you guys are able to block website scaling through font increase? I've tried to do this, but it does not work. Fonts are still increases no matter what font-size I set in html tag.

Comment: @WoutDeRooms Wow, Thanks for this, This might answer a question of many.

Comment: how about mobile browsers? still 16px?

Comment: I will only add that changing the OS text size does not change the browser default font size (as far as I know).