# Default font size across browser

Tags: html

Is 16px the default font size in all browser or are their outliers. I know user can change it but I am referring to the one provided by default by the browser.

Comment: At least all common-used have default font-size 16px by default.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is 16px, according to [this source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size):

> If you haven't set the font size anywhere on the page, then it is the browser default, which is often 16px.

as well as [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29511983/is-the-default-font-size-of-every-browser-16px-why).