# Is is possible to overwrite the browser's default font-size in media queries using EMs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts, media-queries

A lot of people think that **1em** = **16px**. This is **not true**, `1em` = `value of your browser font-size which is most of the time 16px`. While it is not common to change browser default font-size, it is still an easy to change setting.

Given this situation, it is still easy to overwrite the **em** value from an `HTML` element perspective since it uses the top element's font-size. For example:

```
html {
     font-size: 20px; 
}
```

This simple style would cascade down to the rest of the document and **1em** would effectively become **20px**.

The problem is, when using CSS with `media queries`, the value of the **em** seems to be stuck at the browser style level and not the top level element. For example:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 2em) {
    ...some style...
}
```

If we consider the previous example with the **20px** HTML overwrite, one could expect that **2em** in that context refers to the top level element and would have a value of **40px**. But it does not, it will be `2 * browser default font-size` (e.g. 16px, so 36px). Even worse, if you customized your browser font-size to **24px**, **2em** will effectively have a value of **48px**.

Is there ways around this? The main concern is that it's hard to predict style of media queries if we cannot overwrite the browser default font-size. This value becomes unpredictable, which means your style will also be.

I can think of a complex way using JavaScript to get the browser default font-size but I can't stop wondering why media queries don't use the top element's font-size instead of the browser's default font-size. I'm also hoping there is a better way to handle this which does not require complex JavaScript.

To summarize I'm looking for either:

1. A way to overwrite the default browser font-size value when using media queries.
2. A simple way to get the default browser font-size.

Comment: Forgive the question but, why are you looking to measure the media query in ems?  If you are setting the font size in pixels at the html element, you know what you want 2em to evaluate to in this case, no?

Comment: @anied Good question but EMs offers capabilities that would become a nightmare to implement in pixels. They are more dynamic and can be especially useful for responsive design. There is a lot of good articles that can provides details on this.

Comment: I definitely agree that an em-based approach to your CSS is preferred.  But whenever I have created or seen examples of em-based CSS, the way it has been implemented is setting the HTML element's font-size in px, writing all your other CSS in ems, and then writing the media queries viewport width targets in pixels.  This particular means of trying to evaluate the viewport/screensize in ems seems unusual to me--- not that that means it is incorrect, I'm just wondering if you are certain this is the correct approach...

Comment: A query with min-width in `em` does not make a lot of sense, because unless you're setting the font through a `@font-face`, you know nothing about the *width* of the font that gets used. The CSS `font-size` property sets the *vertical distance between successive baselines*, and so sayz nothing about heights. In fact, it's not even the true "height of letters in the font" so your media queries really should be based on absolute units like pixels, millmeters, etc, not relative values like em, ex, or percentages. Top-level rules (`html`, `body`) should be in absolutes.

Comment: @anied I understand that it's less common to have media-queries in EMs but imagine if you want to have a smaller font-size in mobile screen width, you would expect some media query rules to stay the same for example. This is where EMs in media query can avoid spaghetti CSS by keeping the breakpoint equivalent in different layout.

Comment: as a further note: 1em is defined by the metadata in the font used, **not** by the browser. Not all fonts have glyph metrics that perfectly sit in their em quad, so you can have a font that looks like any other at 16px, even though its em quad size is 500 pixels. The only true way to find out how many pixels correspond to 1em is to set a font on an HTML element, fix its size to some `em` value, then measure its BoundingClientRect after reflow and redrawing, and then running the actual "I set it to X em and it's Y pixels, so for this font 1em is Y/X pixels".

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I'm not sure I understand your point. EMs always translate to a pixel value, but are relative to the parent element. I would expect media queries's EM value to be relative to the top level element's pixel value but in fact it is not which is the whole reason I'm asking this question. I still see a lot of benefit in using EMs in media queries and a lot of articles recommend this approach but none of them mentioned the concern of the browser font-size which to me seems problematic.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Are you sure about this? I just tested changing my browser font-size to different pixel values and they match the 1em value without CSS. This is the first time I'm hearing anything about EM having anything to do with font-face. I thought EMs were always related to the pixel size of the font.

Comment: Yes: for *some* fonts it'll seem to do exactly the right thing, but not *all* fonts, so while it's tempting to pretend the simpler thing is going on, that's not what's actually going on.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans It would be great to have concrete common examples because to me it sounds more about some unexpected/edge case than the standard. Actually made me think of Zalgo: https://eeemo.net/ (which I'm honestly not planning to ever support)

Comment: em is a relative unit, if you want something easier to override use px

Comment: @chiliNUT you have the same behavior I described with pixels... and to be honest you have to be a bit masochist if you want to be responsive and use pixels

Comment: @NicolasBouvrette thats an interesting point, when I'm doing responsive design I typically don't need the font size to be responsive, but sometimes I do. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can think of a complex way using JavaScript to get the browser default font-size but I can't stop wondering why media queries don't use the top element's font-size instead of the browser's default font-size.

As the name implies, media queries are designed to query information about the *media* as represented by the user agent. Hence browser, not root element. If you want queries to be based off of the root element you're looking for element queries, something which today isn't available in production in any form.

> To summarize I'm looking for either:
>
> 1. A way to overwrite the default browser font-size value when using media queries.

That would require changing what value `font-size: medium` corresponds to (see [What is an "em" if the font-size of the document is specified in ems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10470727/what-is-an-em-if-the-font-size-of-the-document-is-specified-in-ems)), which is not possible.

> 2. A simple way to get the default browser font-size.

Keyword values for font-size [compute to their corresponding absolute lengths](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-3/#font-size-prop). You could, in theory, use JavaScript to get the computed font size (which coincides with CSS's definition of "computed value" in this specific case) of any element with a specified value of `font-size: medium`, then put that value in your media queries, but this requires implementing all your media queries using JavaScript `window.matchMedia()` instead of CSS `@media`. Which is anything but simple.

Comment: thanks for confirming my fears :) Looking forward to see element queries part of the CSS standard someday.

Answer (score 0):

You can use rem units instead of em units. Em work with it's parent element. What I mean by that If you set base font-size: 20px and you have two ul one inside of one and you set parent ul font size 2em and child ul font-size set 2em than parent ul have font-size 40px but child ul have font-size 80px. Because em follow his parent element. See code below

```css
html {
  font-size: 20px;
}

ul {
  font-size: 2em;
}

ul ul {
  
  font-size: 2em;

}
```

```html
<ul>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam obcaecati amet, labore dignissimos itaque vero odio ipsa repellat, eum natus qui ipsum quidem. Quisquam voluptates, fugiat doloribus ad aperiam corrupti!
      <ul>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing   elit. Enim deleniti labore minus laborum nobis impedit excepturi nostrum temporibus ipsam rerum, cupiditate ex veniam, delectus odio earum a id dolor expedita?
      </ul>
</ul>
```

But if you use rem unit you don't face this kind of problem. See code below

```css
html {
 font-size: 20px;
}


ul {
 font-size: 2rem;
}

ul ul {
 font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<ul>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam obcaecati amet, labore dignissimos itaque vero odio ipsa repellat, eum natus qui ipsum quidem. Quisquam voluptates, fugiat doloribus ad aperiam corrupti!
    <ul>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim deleniti labore minus laborum nobis impedit excepturi nostrum temporibus ipsam rerum, cupiditate ex veniam, delectus odio earum a id dolor expedita?
    </ul>
</ul>
```

I hope it will help you. And also media query work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I was more curious if there was a way to fix the EM/media queries situation given some cross-browsers issues using REMs. This article is discussing some of the issues: https://zellwk.com/blog/media-query-units/