# Default reference font-size of em?

Tags: html, css

What is the default reference font-size of em? Is it the html or body? I've searched the answers in SO but can't find the answer.

Comment: i heard 16px is 1 em, you need to set body font-size:16px

Comment: Unit  Description
em  - Relative to the font-size of the element (2em means 2 times the size of the current font)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most major browsers have standard text set to a default font size of 16px.

*From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size#Ems):*

> If you haven't set the font size anywhere on the page, then it is the
>   browser default, which is often 16px.

It continues on to say:

> So, by default 1em = 16px, and 2em = 32px. If you set a `font-size` of
>   20px on the `body` element, then 1em = 20px and 2em = 40px. Note that
>   the value 2 is essentially a multiplier of the current em size.

Whether the initial font size is declared on the `body` or `html` element is at the discretion of the browser maker. The W3C recommended [*default style sheet*](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/sample.html) doesn't specify an element (or even a font size, for that matter).

Comment: Do you think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10470727/what-is-an-em-if-the-font-size-of-the-document-is-specified-in-ems) is a suitable duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

There is no default font-size for em , em inherits the value of the parent's font size for example if you have a div with a paragraph inside and the font size of the div is set to 18 px then you set the font-size of the paragraph to 0.5 em the font-size in this case will be 9px so it will depend on the parent 's element font size.

in case the parent element was the browser windows the font-size default will be 16 px so 1em will here be equal to 16px

have a look on [this](https://medium.com/@fadysamirsadek/css-units-explained-9a460f5e0f29#.cw5q2ktac) article i wrote before comparing CSS units

Comment: so if I never set any font-size em will inherit from html?

Comment: Exactly which is 16 px in most browsers

Answer (score 0):

The reference font-size of `em` is the last parent element that you've defined the size for. You can also say it as this: `em` unit is relative to the element's current size.

You can see the difference in the both snippet. In the second one the font size of `<p>` is double of the the first one.

```css
body{
  font-size:10px;
}
p{
  font-size:2em;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

```css
body{
  font-size:10px;
}
.container{
  font-size:20px;
}
p{
  font-size:2em;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: so if I never set any font-size em will inherit from html?

Comment: yes. it is predefined in the browser (its called user-agent stylesheet). 16 px to be exact. you can take a look at it in developer tools (press f12 to open them )